# How do I move this scrolling bar closer to the post area?

Tags: css

If you check out this link (http://noahsdad.com/state-fair-texas-2011/) you'll notice that scrolling side bar to the left of the content area. I'm trying to get it to be closer to the content area, any ideas how on to do this?

Thanks.

In the options of the plug in they give me this, I'm assuming I have to make the css changes in their code, instead of my own stylesheet?

```
#dd_ajax_float{
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-120px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `margin-left` element of `#dd_ajax_float` to something like `-100px` instead of `-120px`

I was able to add this to your page and make it work..not sure where you are linking the style sheet for that floating area

```
<style type="text/css">
    #dd_ajax_float
    {
        margin-left: -100px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confused also. It'a the buffer (digg digg) sharer, and it tells me to enter in the css into the plug in options, and not my style sheet. I don't undertand that. Any idea why that's the way they want you to do it?

Comment: I added the css code they have in the plug in options. There is also an option in their plug in to add php into my theme which will give me more options to style it says. But I don't really understand it. Seems like I should be able to use some css to do that. Should I enter in the code you pasted into their plug in options ?

Comment: @RickSmith On your added code just modify the `margin-left` to a lower number like `-100px` and it should move closer

Comment: Ok, I changed that within their code. Thanks! By the way, any ideas on how to make it go a little bit higher?

Comment: @RickSmith you can change `margin-top` to `-20px` but thats as high unless you modify the code that makes it stick is modified as well.  If its more when you scroll it will be above the viewable area.

Comment: Cool thanks, I just made the change. It looks much better. :)